# Git - different submodules in two different branches

Tags: git, git-submodules

My super-project has two branches - *master* and *dev*. I initially had a submodule in both these branches, but now I need to keep it only in the *dev* branch. To do that, I switched to the *master* branch and removed it from there (following the instructions [outlined here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial)). Now every time I switch from the *dev* branch to the *master* branch, I get a message saying **warning: unable to rmdir path/to/submodule: Directory not empty**. Also, every time I do `git status` in the *master* branch, git lists the submodule under Untracked files.

Is there a way I can tell git not to complain about this submodule? I tried adding the submodule path to `.gitignore` in the master branch, but that doesn't seem to have helped. Also, I am curious why git does not complain when a folder exists in one branch and not in another, but it does when a submodule exists in one branch and not in another?

**Edit:** I did not delete the relevant section from the `.git/config` file when removing the submodule as I still wanted it in the dev branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more complete instructions on how to delete a submodule in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309):

The point which trips most of the users trying to remove a submodule is:

```
git rm --cached path_to_submodule (no trailing slash)
```

That is because they generally deleted (simple OS `rm` command, not a `git rm` command) the path to the submodule, which means it is no longer visible.
And yet, it is still recorded in the index.

---

If you need to remove the submodule in one branch only (and keep it in the other), then you need to:

- **not modify `.git/config`**: this is a local config used by the all repos (and all its branches): so no `git submodule deinit` here (that only cleans what is in `.git` regarding submodule).
- remove the submodule entry in:

  - `.gitmodules` file (you can have different content of that file in different branches)
  - the index: `git rm --cached path_to_submodule` (no trailing slash): again a modification you do only in one branch.

Comment: Sorry I answered my question in a hurry; I am still looking for an answer. Won't the process described in that page delete the submodule from both my branches? I still want the submodule to exist in my dev branch though. Moreover, the description of the `submodule deinit` command seems like it is just a wrapper for the [commands I used](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial)

Comment: @VarunVats sure, I have edited my answer to address your specific question.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did. I did not delete the submodule section from my `.git/config` file. My problem is that every time I switch from the `dev` branch to the `master` branch, I get a message saying **warning: unable to rmdir path/to/submodule: Directory not empty**. Also, every time I do git status in the master branch, git lists the submodule under **Untracked files**. Is there any way I can get rid of these messages?

Comment: @VarunVats regarding the git status, you could add a .gitignore (only in the master branch) in order to ignore the root directory of your (previous) submodule.