# Different git submodules within different branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

Is it possible to have different submodules within different branches? For example, branch 1 would only see submodule 1 and branch 2 would only see submodule 2.

One option is to use `git submodule deinit` before moving to another branch, and then running `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` after returning to the first branch. This works, but adds a number of additional steps every time a new branch is to be checked out.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247718/git-different-submodules-in-two-different-branches), but this was 10 years ago and I'm wondering if there is a more up-to-date way of doing this.

Comment: 1st thing to try is [`git checkout --recurse-submodules`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55631474/7976758). Please read also https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551146/7976758

Comment: 2nd thing to try is `post-checkout` and `post-merge` hooks — you don't need to do submodules cleanup/setup manually. Two examples of such hooks: [small](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37383406/7976758) and [bigger](https://github.com/chaitanyagupta/gitutils/blob/973696c7e556d6a67ef890e159dbd0290233a820/submodule-hooks/post-merge-checkout).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @phd, the `--recurse-submodules` is the way to go

Comment: Deleting a submodule work tree is so fraught I doubt automating it will ever be built in, there's just too much potential for deleting things that shouldn't be deleted.